# Auto logout after 30 min

Tags: apigee, usergrid

I am new in apigee. I am using below function for a login in application:

```
  client.login(username, password,
      function (err) {
        if (err) {
          alert('Invalid username or password.');
          $(".ajax_loader").hide();
          $("#login-btn").show();
        } else {
          //login succeeded
          client.getLoggedInUser(function(err, data, user) {
            if(err) {
              //error - could not get logged in user
              alert(err);
            }
```

And I want to set auto logout after 30 min, is it possible, and if yes, where we can set this limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no feature for auto logout.  Possibly this is an enhancement the usergrid team would consider.